# Twitter bootstrap tooltip directions not working?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I noticed that my twitter bootstrap tooltips were not respecting `data-position`.

So, I headed over to the [Twitter Bootstrap tooltips demo](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips), specifically looking at the "Tooltip on X" examples, and this is what I get:

[image: No Direction support?]

It looks like there is no support for the direction?

But, the popovers, which the tooltips inherit from (or possibly it's the other way around?) work:
[image: Direction support?]

#### Browsers tried:

Chromium 24.0 on Ubuntu 12.10
Firefox 19.0 on Ubuntu 12.10

Is this a bug that should be reported, or something else going on here?

Answer (score 23):

Jsfiddle [Jsfiddle with tooltip working](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/vSTLU/2/)

Its not a bug , but we need to initialize them  .
**Important** Bootstrap website states "For performance reasons, the tooltip and popover data-apis are opt in, meaning you must initialize them yourself." [Bootstrap website Tooltip section](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)

```
<div class="navbar tooltip-demo">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a class="top" title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" data-original-title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</a></li>
          <li><a class="right" title="" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" data-original-title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</a></li>
          <li><a class="bottom" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" data-original-title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</a></li>
          <li><a class="left" title="" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" data-original-title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

The javascript to use , you will have to initialize

```
$('a').tooltip();
```

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way I have found to initialize tooltips with Bootstrap is to match their code so any of your tooltips will work.

```
$(function () {
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
});
```

OR you can actually add this line to the very end of your bootstrap-tooltip.js file

```
}(window.jQuery);  //<-- last line of bootstrap-tooltip.js

$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
```

I basically planned on if I am going to use the tooltip code, then I might as well have it enabled by default. So, I put this in my bootstrap-tooltip.js file.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's a bug. From http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/application.js
you can see the demo is called with 'selector' option.

```
$('.tooltip-demo').tooltip({
  selector: "a[data-toggle=tooltip]"
});
```

But the 'show' function in [bootstrap-tooltip.js](https://raw.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/master/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js) will not check for 'selector' option when handling 'placement'. Therefore bug occurred.

```
    placement = typeof this.options.placement == 'function' ?
      this.options.placement.call(this, $tip[0], this.$element[0]) :
      this.options.placement
```

Demo for this bug: http://jsfiddle.net/indream/xFC7G/
Related github issue: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6832

Comment: Good job for finding there is indeed an issue with the Bootstrap demo