# bootstrap tooltip being cut off

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm trying to add bootstrap tooltips to some icons on a list, but the tooltip is partially hidden by the row height:

[image]

What style do I need to add to my code below to have the tooltip hover on top?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in c.data.list track by $index" class="list-group-item">
      <div class="flex">
        <div style="margin-right:auto;">
          <span class="h4">{{item.short_description}}</span>
          <div>
            <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o m-l-xs"></i><span style="padding-left: 5px;">Last Updated: {{item.last_updated}}</span></small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="h4">
          <a class="link" ng-click="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Preview"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>   
          <a class="link" ng-click="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Download"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>   
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023239/twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-directions-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023239/twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-directions-not-working). Try initializing the tooltips first?

Comment: can use share some css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap tooltip directions not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023239/twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-directions-not-working)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 12):

I had an issue with tooltips being cut off as well and what worked for me was to set the data-container to 'body'. For example:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-container="body" title="bla">
```

Comment: This works, should be accepted answer.
See bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#example-using-the-container-option

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! ^_^